# How to find information about a Dachau Internee?

Tags: 20th-century, germany, world-war-2, bavaria, berlin

I am posting here as I have no idea where to begin. And information that I have is limited and Im hoping that somebody can point me in the right direction.

My Great Uncle was a political prisoner interned for 11 years in the Dachau camp outside of Munich, Germany.

He was last heard of in Berlin.

Obviously, he would have passed by now but I would like very much to find any official records of his internment and his movements upon his release in 1945.

Answer (score 5):

Your best place to start would be [Steve Morse's Dachau record search](http://stevemorse.org/dachau/dachau.html), and see if you can find your Great Uncle.

Morse's [Dachau intro page](http://www.stevemorse.org/dachau/intro.htm) gives a good overview of the extent of Dachau records available. Also see [Dachau Concentration Camp Records](http://www.jewishgen.org/databases/holocaust/0050_dachauindexing.html) on JewishGen which provides additional information about the records available.

Comment: first link was simply, but asks for a id number of which we don't have…and he was a German communist so not sure if he would of had any tattoo of any number on his body either. but thank you so kindly for these directions.

Answer (score 4):

The German Red Cross still maintains a [WWII tracing service](https://www.drk-suchdienst.de/en/initiate-tracing-requests/tracing-request-second-world-war) that would seem to [apply to your case](http://www.drk.de/angebote/migration-und-suchdienst/suchdienst.html) (my translation):

> You're looking for relatives in relation to the second world war? For
>   over 65 years, the DRK tracing service has been conducting investigations
>   concerning POWs and civil prisoners, missing Wehrmacht soldiers,
>   civilians abducted and children lost in the second world war.

Comment: Michael, this has already been covered on another thread and the service is not available at the moment.

Comment: It's a separate service from the ICRC one that is unavailable, but I will inquire whether they are also affected.

Comment: Update: the service operates independantly from the ICRC and is currently available.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the update, good news.

Answer (score 4):

Camp records are free on [Fold3](http://www.fold3.com/). You need to sign up to view scans, but it's definitely worth a try. I found a Buchenwald card of a remote uncle there myself.